# js проверить наличие элемента 1 на любом уровне вложенности в элементе 2

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте,

есть элемент elem, как проверить есть среди его родителей /(пра)*?родителей/ элемент wrapper.

Я делал обход родитель->прародитель->прапра.. и сверял, пока не наткнусь на эл. wrapper или body. Тогда цикл заканчивался. Работает, но жутко выглядит.

Есть ли более лаконичный способ?
Что-то на подобии - wrapper.getElementById('elem') ?
Только не имея id. Имея переменные wrapper и elem

Большое спасибо

Comment: Приведите свой код, чтобы нам было от чего отталкиваться. В общем случае Вам может помочь while и свойство элемента parentNode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Самый простой способ судя по всему воспользоваться методом [contains](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/contains)

```js
var div = document.querySelector('div');
var span = document.querySelector('span');
var label = document.querySelector('label');

console.log('div содержит span', div.contains(span));
console.log('div содержит label', div.contains(label));
```

```html
<div>
  <div>
    <label>label1</label>
  </div>
</div>
<span>span</span>
```

Можно воспользоваться функцией [Node.compareDocumentPosition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/compareDocumentPosition).

Если в результате будет установлен бит *DOCUMENT_POSITION_CONTAINED_BY* значит элемент содержит проверяемый элемент.

Например:

```js
function checkContains(parent, child) {
  return (parent.compareDocumentPosition(child) & Node.DOCUMENT_POSITION_CONTAINED_BY) !== 0;
}
var div = document.querySelector('div');
var span = document.querySelector('span');
var label = document.querySelector('label');

console.log('div содержит span', checkContains(div, span));
console.log('div содержит label', checkContains(div, label));
```

```html
<div>
  <label>label1</label>
</div>
<span>span</span>
```

Если в результате будет установлен бит *DOCUMENT_POSITION_CONTAINS* значит элемент находится внутри проверяемого элемента.

Например:

```js
function isNested(child, parent) {
  return (child.compareDocumentPosition(parent) & Node.DOCUMENT_POSITION_CONTAINS) !== 0;
}
var div = document.querySelector('div');
var span = document.querySelector('span');
var label = document.querySelector('label');

console.log('span внутри div', isNested(span, div));
console.log('label внутри div', isNested(label, div));
```

```html
<div>
  <label>label1</label>
</div>
<span>span</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно через `querySelector` проверять наличие элемента

```js
(function() {
  
  if(document.querySelector('div').querySelectorAll('span').length > 0){
    console.log('В div есть span');
  }else{
    console.log('В div нету span');
  };
  
  if(document.querySelector('label').querySelectorAll('span').length > 0){
    console.log('В label есть span');
  }else{
    console.log('В label нету span');
  };
  
  if(document.querySelector('p').querySelectorAll('span').length > 0){
    console.log('В p есть span');
  }else{
    console.log('В p нету span');
  };
})();
```

```html
<div><span></span></div>
<label><div><span></span></div></label>
<p></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Как я понял, решения нет, и один из элементов все-равно нужно получить по селектору....

То что я писал в вопросе - по селектору элемента:
wrapper.getElementById("elem");

Или наоборот, по селектору wrapper:
elem.closest("#wrapper");

Второй вариант только нагуглил.. В принципе он мне подходит. Если кто знает еще варианты - пишите.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function manualClosest(elem, parent){
    if (elem.parentElement == parent) return true;
    else if (elem.parentElement = document.body) return false;
    else return manualClosest(elem.parentElement, parent);
}
```

Comment: А по `querySelector` не?